# Prior on sum of bernoulli variables

Tags: bayesian, modeling, variational-bayes

I wish to model my data as follows:

$$
y\sim\mathcal{N}(X\beta,\sigma^2)\\
\beta_i\sim\mathcal{N}(5,1)^{z_i}\mathcal{N}(0,1)^{1-z_i}\\
z_i\sim logit(\gamma_i)\\
\gamma_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\gamma_{i-1},1)
$$

I wish have to far more of $z_i=1$ than $z_i=0$ (90% to be more accurate).

**Question is** How can I encode this information in a Bayesian way.

**What I've thought so far** is to do something like $p(z_i)\propto logit(\gamma_i)\exp(-(\sum z_i-90)^2)$ but this would be a nightmare for the inference algorithm (variational Bayes) that I am using since $q(z_i)\propto \exp(-C_1z_i^2-C_2z_i)$.

**Ideas:** Is there a smarter way of doing something similar by maybe even introducing another latent variable, and another level to the hierarchical probability structure?

Comment: You cannot write the prior on $z_i$ as depending on all $z_j$'s. However you can center the $\gamma_i$'s on large values, for instance using an AR(1) or an MA(1) structure: $$\gamma_i=\mu_0-\varrho(\gamma_{i-1}-\mu_0)+\epsilon_i$$ or $$\gamma_i=\mu_o+\epsilon_i-\varphi_i\epsilon_{i-1}\,.$$

Comment: There is nothing stopping you writing the prior the way I did. Only thing is the normalising constant isn't analytical. I also tried something similar to what you mentioned. Only problem is you still don't have much control over how many $z_i$s are 1.

Comment: Then modify your notation from $\phi(z_i)$ to $\phi(z_1,\ldots, z_n)$! To get a large number of $1$'s, you can first generate the number of $1$'s and then generate the $z_i$'s conditional on that number.